# Looping multiplot in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I can never get both the loops and layout to work.
My data looks  like this

```
2   1   -93.50882606    -93.51697017    -93.51086209
2   2   -93.51324833    -93.51714636    -93.51422284
2   3   -93.52672325    -93.53627468    -93.52911111
2   4   -93.51306982    -93.52395431    -93.51579094
2   5   -93.50908482    -93.51902598    -93.51157011
2   6   -93.50825891    -93.51587124    -93.51016199
2   7   -93.50822884    -93.51691667    -93.51040080
3   1   -93.50792762    -93.51624138    -93.51000606
3   2   -93.51196983    -93.51499451    -93.51272600
3   3   -93.50793572    -93.51664664    -93.51011345
3   4   -93.50768256    -93.51618396    -93.50980791
3   5   -93.50771675    -93.51656535    -93.50992890
4   1   -93.50762338    -93.51564665    -93.50962919
4   2   -93.53234566    -93.54136850    -93.53460137
```

And i want plots with values from columns 2,3,4,5 untill the value of the first column changes. Then it should start a new multiplot underneath it.

The numbers in the first column are always different so i don't know how to make the loop without knowing how many there will be and not set multiplot layout on fixed amount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will most likely require some external processing of the input file. One approach could be as follows

```
reset
set terminal pngcairo enhanced
set output 'fig.png'

set xtics out nomirror

set ytics out nomirror
set ytics format '%.3f'

set xr [1:7]

set key bottom right

#find the number of unique (consecutive) values from the first column
N = system("gawk '{print $1}' input.dat | uniq | wc -l")

#adjust multiplot setup
set multiplot layout N, 1

do for [i=1:N] {
    #find the corresponding group identifier
    idx = system(sprintf("gawk '{print $1}' input.dat | uniq | head -n%d | tail -n1", i))

    set title sprintf("group %s", idx)

    plotCmd=sprintf("<gawk 'BEGIN{p=v=0;} {if(!p||$1!=v){v=$1;p+=1} if(p==%d){print p,$2,$3,$4,$5} if(p>%d){exit;}}' input.dat", i, i)
    plot \
        plotCmd u 2:3 w l lc rgb 'black' t 'column 3', \
        '' u 2:4 w l lc rgb 'dark-red' t 'column 4', \
        '' u 2:5 w l lc rgb 'royalblue' t 'column 5'
}
```

The strategy is to:

1. invoke `gawk` and `uniq` in order to determine the number of unique (consecutive) ids which appear in the first column of the input file (assumed to be named `input.dat`)
2. create corresponding multiplot layout
3. iterate over all groups and for each group, plot the corresponding chunk of data. To this end, the script above invokes `gawk` again to filter the corresponding rows (it just keeps track of the group number of the value in the first column, prints all rows for a particular group of interest and finally terminates once the entire group has been loaded)

This then produces:
[image]